# In WPF application using MVVM pattern On button click need to show alert box?

Tags: wpf

How I can bind button in xaml so that using mvvm pattern I can show alert box on button click?

Thanks.

Comment: If somebody who has downvoted could explain why, it would be useful. A new user has been downvoted with no explanation for simply posting a question. Granted, this is not an ideal question, but downvoting without any followup does not help anyone.

Comment: Hey and welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you please post your code, explain what you already tried and where you failed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you,we need a bit more context. Can you post what you've tried so far, what didn't work, the results of your research, etc? Have a look at how to make a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alert boxes in WPF MVVM are a bit of a headache, however it is reasonably straightforward once you have a basic framework for your program written (ie, View, ViewModel in place).

This tutorial is particularly good at explaining the idea of bindings, and uses an alaert box as part fo the example.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute

Comment: Thanks Alex for taking positive side in favor of me.Your given link works for me.Thanks Alex :)

Comment: @Rohit In the interest of balance, I should say I didn't really act in favour. You asked a question with enough detail to understand what you needed to do, but the question wasn't ideally asked. As Area and Fabio have said, posting some detail about what you've tried already and what has gone awry is always helpful and appreciated. I'm glad I could help, and welcome to SO.